# Kendo UI Stock Charts does not display on Safari

Tags: safari, kendo-ui

I'm attempting to create a stock chart using Kendo UI. I created the chart and it displays fine on every browser (IE, FireFox, Chrome) EXCEPT for Safari, where it will only display a default placeholder chart area but no data, numbers, chart info, range slider, etc.

Here also is my code in jsbin: http://jsbin.com/ucoliq/4/

This only occurs when using Stock Charts, otherwise I have no issues creating other charts and displaying it with Safari. If anyone has any suggestions or ideas that could help fix this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess that you mean Safari on Windows... because Safari on Mac works fine (for me)! Which OS are you using?

Comment: I've tested it with both Safari on Windows (Windows 7) and the iPad, and neither one works for me. I haven't had the opportunity to test it on a Mac, it's interesting that it does work on that though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Safari barks at the date format. You can confirm this by executing:

```
new Date("2011-06");
> Invalid Date
```

Switching to a more conventional format (2011/06/01) seems to solve this.

See http://jsbin.com/ucoliq/6/edit